# How do I Implement this design to remove code repetition

Tags: java, design-patterns

My application has about 50 entities that are displayed in grid format in the UI. All 50 entities have CRUD operations. Most of the operations have the standard flow

ie. for get, read entities from repository, convert to  DTO and return a list of DTO's.
for create/update/delete - get DTO's - convert to entities, use repository to create/update/delete on DB, return updated DTOs

Mind you that for SOME entities, there are also some entity specific operations that have to be done.

Currently, we have a get/create/update/delete method for all our entities like
getProducts
createProducts
updateProducts
getCustomers
createCustomers
updateCustomers
in each of these methods, we use the Product/Customer repository to perform the CRUD operation AFTER conversion from entity -> dto and vice versa.

I feel there is a lot of code repetition and there must be a way by which we can remove so many of these methods.

Can i use some pattern (COMMAND PATTERN) to get away with code repetition?

Comment: @AdamArold, I should imagine that if there are 50 odd entities, that's a lot of code to dump into a question. A better question for the op may be, did you auto generate the code from a database for example? In NetBeans for example, I can point it at a database and get it to generate most of the crud. It makes it easy to maintain. Any additional logic that will be specific should sit outside in a wrapper (see Decorator)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Spring Data JPA](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/) or [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) project.  It does away with boilerplate code for DAO.

I believe it basically uses AOP to interpret calls like

```
findByNameandpassword (String name,String passwd)
```

to do a query based upon the parameters passed in selecting the fields in the method name (only an interface).

Being a spring project it has very minimal requirements for spring libraries.

Comment: To add, for conversion from entity <-> DTO you could use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/), saves you again some code.

Comment: I use [Moo](http://github.com/geoffreywiseman/Moo) for that job, but certainly Dozer's another reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have 2 ways to do this.

**First way: Code generation**

Write a class that can generate the code given a database schema.
Note that this you will create basic classes for each entity.
If you have custom code (code specific to certain entities) you can put that in subclasses so that it doesn't get overwritten when you regenerate the basic classes.

Object instatiation should be via Factory methods so that the correct subclass is used.

Make sure you add comments in the generated code that clearly states that the code is generated automatically (so that people don't start editing them directly).

**Second way: Reflection**

This solution, while being more elegant, is also more complex.
Instead of generating one basic class for each entity you have one basic class that can handle any entity. The class would be using reflection to access the DTO:s.

If you have custom code (code specific to certain entities) you can put that in other classes. These other classes would be injected into the generic class.

Using reflection would require a strict naming policy on your DTO:s.

**Conclusion**

I have been in a project using the first method in a migration project to generate DTO classes for the service interface between the new application server (running java) and the fat clients and it worked quite well. We had more than 100 generated DTO classes. I am aware that what you are attempting is slighty different. Editing database records is a generic problem (all projects need it) but there aren't (m)any frameworks for it.

I have been thinking about creating a generic tool or framework for it but I have never gotten around to it.